# ImportError: No module named 'yolo_utils' : Analytics Vidhya

Tags: yolo

I was running the code given here:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/12/practical-guide-object-detection-yolo-framewor-python/#comment-156059
I get error " [
ImportError: No module named ‘yolo_utils’
So I copy pasted the source code of yolo_utils.py. But, it still gave error" ImportError: cannot import name ‘read_classes’"

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy this code**[strong text](https://github.com/iArunava/YOLOv3-Object-Detection-with-OpenCV/blob/master/yolo_utils.py)** into q yolo_utils.py file and add it into your project